# Syntax error in While loop

Tags: command-line, bash

Here is my code -

```
#!/bin/bash
find FileFrom -type f -name "*" > prodRefresh.txt
filename="prodRefresh.txt"
while read -r line; do
    name=$line
    echo "Name read from file - $name"
done < $filename
```

while trying to execute via command prompt, giving below error  -

```
copyAndCreate.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
copyAndCreate.sh: line 7: `done < $filename'
```

Please help me to solve this. Thanks

Comment: Check your script for DOS-style (CRLF) line endings (ex. `file copyAndCreate.sh`)

Comment: @steeldriver why it is giving error to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will happen if your file has Windows style line endings (`\r\n`) instead of regular Unix ones (`\n`). You have probably edited this file in a Windows environment at some point, and that changed the line endings and the extra `\r` is messing with your script. The solution is to fix the line endings:

```
dos2unix copyAndCreate.sh
```

Or, if you don't have `dos2unix`, try:

```
sed -i 's/\r//' copyAndCreate.sh
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to edit Linux files on Linux - or at least use Notepad++, which let's you choose the type of line endings in the file.